# Meaning of killing of

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Does "killing of my father" mean that father killed someone or he is killed by someone. Or is it double meaning?

> Every year the Natives celebrated the killing of my father all over again.

Comment: This needs a source for the quote. I can answer when you have finished asking the question.

Comment: @James Unfortunately i don't have the full context.

Comment: A google search on the quote shows that it is from the 2002 film "The Gangs of New York", for which there's a Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Boyep.  I asked for the source.  That means your source.  Where did you hear or read this?  Apparently it is from a film. If that is not where you heard it then please tell us what your source is.

Comment: This is from "context.reverso", it's from app so i can't give you the link because app does not let me do this.

Comment: _The killing of X_ normally means that X was killed.

Comment: Is that a translation from an app?? Generally, killing is not "celebrated". I mean....It's crappy usage. Very poor. "celebrated a day of remembrance for my father who was assasinated" would be the idea.

Comment: @Lambie  That would depend on whether or not they liked said person. It's not considered civilised behaviour to celebrate a death, even of an adversary, but it's perfectly natural, particularly if referring to a despotic dictator or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used in this way, it refers to the occasion that the father was killed.  Consider the related phrases "the liberation of Auschwitz" or "the sack of Troy".  It's always the verb that happened *to* the noun being mentioned.